# Smooth fill animation change (encreasing, decreasing) in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm making a UI for my 2d unity game and i'm trying to use Mathf.lerp to make fill of the hearts image represanting player's health decrease, increase smoothly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthUIController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject heartContainer;
    private float fillValue;

    void Update()
    {
        fillValue = (float)GameController.Health;
        fillValue = fillValue / GameController.MaxHealth;
        heartContainer.GetComponent<Image>().fillAmount = fillValue; // this is where i need to use Mathf.lerp
    }
}
```

I've read mathf.lerp manual but i still don't get how it works

Comment: What don't you understand about the documentation?  It says **Linearly interpolates between a and b by t.  The parameter t is clamped to the range [0, 1].  When t = 0 returns a.  When t = 1 return b.  When t = 0.5 returns the midpoint of a and b.**

Comment: Check my answer. Lerp is not the right way to do a smooth fill animation, but I describe how you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `Lerp` to have a smoother fill animation, you can do it like this:

```
Image image;
public float fillSmoothness = 0.01f;

void Start()
{
    image = heartContainer.GetComponent<Image>();
}

void Update()
{
    float prevFill = image.fillAmount;
    float currFill = (float)GameController.Health / GameController.MaxHealth;
    if(currFill > prevFill) prevFill = Mathf.Min(prevFill + fillSmoothness, currFill);
    else if (currFill < prevFill) prevFill = Mathf.Max(prevFill - fillSmoothness, currFill);
    image.fillAmount = prevFill;
}
```

In the inspector of the class you can tune `fillSmoothness` to work as you wish.

Comment: Op said he wants to increase/decrease it smoothly. Your code make it instant which is undesirable also same code what OP posted.

Comment: I was adding in the answer, now it is done.

Comment: Great work guys !!! I checked both of these codes and they work, but i will go with Daniel's answer because it's just shorter, but Anders's code is also good (explanations for someone that needs them) Thanks and cheers :)

Comment: @MaxTheNotSoSmart a tip: store the `Image` component in a variable, so you only need to call `GetComponent<Image>()` one time, at `Start()` method. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ben, I think you missed his question. Max wanted a smooth change over time. Here is an example.

```
void Start()
{
    health = maxHealth;
    visibleHealth = health;
}

/// <summary>
/// The image to adjust.
/// </summary>
public Image heartImage;

/// <summary>
/// The players actual health.
/// </summary>
private float health;

/// <summary>
/// The max health.
/// </summary>
public float maxHealth = 100;

/// <summary>
/// The health value we are currently showing.
/// </summary>
private float visibleHealth; 

/// <summary>
/// The health value we are animating from (when we started the animation).
/// </summary>
private float oldHealth;

/// <summary>
/// Current animation time, or <c>-1</c> when not animating.
/// </summary>
private float healthAnimationTimer = -1;
    
/// <summary>
/// How long time in seconds it should take for the image to show the actual health.
/// </summary>
public float timeToAnimate = 2f;

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the players health. 
/// </summary>
public float Health
{
    get { return health; }
    set
    {
        // If the health has not changed, leave.
        if (value == health)
            return; 
        // Note that we use the visible health since we may already be in an animation.
        oldHealth = visibleHealth;
        health = value;
        healthAnimationTimer = 0;
    }
}



void Update()
{
    // Are we animating the health change?
    if(healthAnimationTimer > -1)
    {
        healthAnimationTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (healthAnimationTimer > timeToAnimate)
        {
            // Stop the animation.
            healthAnimationTimer = -1;
            visibleHealth = health;
        }
        else
        {
            visibleHealth = Mathf.Lerp(oldHealth, health, healthAnimationTimer / timeToAnimate);
        }
        Debug.Log( visibleHealth.ToString() + "->" + health.ToString());
        heartImage.fillAmount = visibleHealth / maxHealth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great work guys !!! I checked both of these codes and they work, but i will go with Daniel's answer because it's just shorter, but Anders's code is also good (explanations for someone that needs them) Thanks and cheers :)